# Unexpected T_FUNCTION for function on PHP 5.2

Tags: php, function, syntax-error

I'm using the following function:

```
     function uniqueACF(array $array) {
        $flatten = array();

array_walk_recursive($array, function($value) use(&$flatten) {
            $flatten[] = $value;
     });

        $flatten = array_unique($flatten);  

        return $flatten;
    }
```

This works fine in PHP 5.3, but for PHP 5.2 it will give a 'unexpected T_Funcion for the `array_walk_recursive` line. It probably has to do with the `function($value)` or `use(&$flatten)`.

But I'm not sure how I should make this work on PHP 5.2. How should I rewrite this for PHP 5.2?

Comment: Do not make it work on PHP 5.2, just upgrade your version

Comment: Alright thanks. Is there by the way a error handling system to check errors on other PHP versions? I'm using PHP 5.3 so I don't see the error. Would be nice if I could 'simulate' a 5.2 version to check other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous functions are available from PHP 5.3. That's why it doesn't work in PHP 5.2.

You should really think, why you move to PHP 5.2 - even PHP 5.3 reached already end of life and PHP 5.6 will be released soon.

Comment: I know. This is a function from a plugin, so many people can use it. Actually they need to update to 5.3. Could push them by not updating it.